# Speeding up soaking of cashews for a recipe

Tags: nuts, soaking

I am trying to follow a Sri Lankan recipe that asks me to soak cashews overnight. Since I can't really wait that long, is there a way to speed up this process? Would putting it in hot water help the process?

Comment: what are you soaking the cashews in?

Comment: i am soaking it in water

Comment: 7 years later, what's the recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a pressure cooker would rapidly accelerate the absorption of water. It risks over doing it and also 'cooks' the cashews so this may not be the best solution for your recipe but the pressure vessel would force the moisture inward to the nut.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your cashews in a crock-pot, that would speed up the process. Whether this would turn your cashews into something similar to boiled peanuts, I am not sure, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure cooker is the best option for you, you'll cook them fast. But if the recipe asks you to soak up the cashews all night is for 2 reasons:

1. Get them softer so they'll cook faster
2. To remove the heaviness of the cashews, by throwing away the soaking water